# How do I order results based on two columns conditionally

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two columns: `created_at` and `updated_at`. I wan't to order results of a query by date, if `updated_at` is present in a row, then use this column for ordering, otherwise use `created_at`. Is this possible to do in one query?

Comment: `ORDER BY COALESCE(updated_at, created_at)`?

Comment: @GarethD thanks, I guess that's it. I wasn't aware of that function.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
created_at
,updated_at
,COALESCE(updated_at,created_at) AS MostRecentDate
FROM [Table]
ORDER BY MostRecentDate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use case as following

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN updated_at IS NOT NULL THEN updated_at ELSE created_at END
```